# Filepath not found outside WPF window ctor

Tags: c#, wpf, filepath

I am using following world heatmap in my WPF application:
https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/GeoHeatMap

```
//Geomap 
private static string GEOMAP_PATH = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\\Materials\\GeoMaps\\World.xml";

public MainMaterialWindow()
        {
            //Default application initialization
            InitializeComponent();

            //geomap chart
            var values = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            foreach (actual_headmapdata data in GetWorldHeadmapData())
            {
                values[data.isocode] = data.count;
            }

            geoMap1.HeatMap = values;
            var lang = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            lang["DE"] = "Germany"; // change the language if necessary
            geoMap1.LanguagePack = lang;
            geoMap1.Source = GEOMAP_PATH;

        }
```

What I don't understand is why the filepath is not found if I do something like this.

```
//Geomap 
private static string GEOMAP_PATH = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\\Materials\\GeoMaps\\World.xml";

public MainMaterialWindow()
        {
            //Default application initialization
            InitializeComponent();
            //init GeoMap
            initGeoMap();
        }


public void initGeoMap() {

         //geomap chart
            var values = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            foreach (actual_headmapdata data in GetWorldHeadmapData())
            {
                values[data.isocode] = data.count;
            }

            geoMap1.HeatMap = values;
            var lang = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            lang["DE"] = "Germany"; // change the language if necessary
            geoMap1.LanguagePack = lang;
            geoMap1.Source = GEOMAP_PATH;
            }
```

I get: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "This file  was not found."

So the problem is, why the filepath is not valid anymore once the initialization of the geomap is outside of MainMaterialWindow(). File still exits.

```
XAML:
<lvc:GeoMap x:Name="geoMap1" HeatMap="{Binding Values}" LanguagePack="{Binding LanguagePack}" Margin="10,0,-12,22" />
```

Same happens with full filepath as string: `GEOMAP_PATH="D:\\Dev\\projectname\\bin\\debug\\Materials\\GeoMaps\\World.xml"`

This also only works within MainMaterialWindow(), so it is not about:

private static string GEOMAP_PATH = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)

Comment: Maybe the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Of course it exists...same filepath. File is there otherwise it would not work with above code.

Comment: But it *doesn't* work.  You got "This file was not found."

Comment: You  need to make it clear to us what the difference is between your two examples.  We don't have time to guess.  To me, they look identical.

Comment: Copy paste issue

Comment: Do you expect your files in same folder with executable? Because [GetDirectoryName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=netframework-4.8) returns _the string returned by this method consists of all characters in the path up to but not including the last DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar._, according to MSDN. It returns one level up folder

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski No, I also tried full path as string like: GEOMAP_PATH="D:\\Dev\\projectname\\bin\\debug\\Materials\\GeoMaps\\World.xml" and it works only if the initilization of geomap is inside MainMaterialWindow(). Outside the file is also not found